# How to change mat-icon colour when focus in mat-Input field?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I am using mat-form-field and mat-icon, i want to when i am click or focus inside the mat-form-field(mat-Input field) mat-icon colour should be  changed , when focus out mat-icon remains same previous colour.[(Stackblitz)see in this example & make changes inside](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lyjerjenmja?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** 
preferably in a **[Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)**. 
See **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below style to your code,

```css
.mat-focused .mat-icon {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sir, same mat-focus style work in mat-input text colour also?